# PHP email output change

Tags: php, email, hide

I am looking for some help with script that makes email output from variable partly hidden before the @ like I have email

```
verysecretemail@gmail.com
```

And i need in output to have "randomly" put star there like:

```
ver***@gmail.com
verys*********************@gmail.com
ve*@gmail.com
```

But not like:

```
ver***mail.com
verysecre****ail.com
```

Just random uses of stars (or maybe static) it doesnt metter but before the @ character

I tried something like this

```
$output = substr_replace($val, '********', 2, 7);
```

Where $val = $email;

Comment: I tried something like this $output = substr_replace($val, '********', 2, 7); where $val = $email;

Comment: if your trying to protect email addresses from bot harvesting there are MUCH better methods.

Comment: Just remember that since you are using random... there are problems bound to happen if you later want to "manually" compare an email yesterday and today if the function was run again afterwards. Just use caution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$mail = "verysecretemail@gmail.com";

$mailparts = explode("@", $mail);

$output = substr($mailparts[0],0,rand(2,5)) . str_repeat("*",rand(1,16));
$output .= "@" . $mailparts[1];
```

Comment: I have it like variable so changing in every person :)

Comment: If you are referring to the first line, it's just to set an initial value. Change the first line to however you retrieve the email, e.g. `$mail = $user->email;`.

Comment: So this will replace characters before the @ character? that is what I need i think ..

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
$asterisks = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen(substr($address, 0, strpos($address, "@"))); $i++)
    $asterisks = $asterisks . "*"; //This loop sets the required number of asterisks
$address = str_replace(substr($address, 0, strpos($address, "@") - 1), $asterisks); 
//everything before the '@' is replaced by an asterisk
```

Comment: This always leaves three characters and adds three asterisks. It will even chop of '@gm', you need to substract the three initial characters: `$address = str_replace(substr($address, 3, strpos($address, "@")-3), "***");`.

Comment: I've edited it so that the '@' remains intact and to make it more dynamic, but I'm sure that my new logic should work. You have the best solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier to read method of doing this using sub strings:

```
$emails = array(
    'verysecretemail@gmail.com',
    'example@example.org',
    'someotheremail@example.com',
);

function obfuscate_email($email) {
    $at_position = strpos($email, '@');
    $chop = rand(1, $at_position - 1);
    $mask = str_repeat('*', rand(4, 8));

    $partial_address = substr($email, 0, $chop);
    $domain = substr($email, $at_position);
    return $partial_address . $mask . $domain;
}

foreach($emails as $email) {
    var_dump(obfuscate_email($email));
}

// Output:
// string(18) "ver*****@gmail.com"
// string(24) "exam********@example.org"
// string(17) "s****@example.com"
```

A running example can be found at http://ideone.com/21HKd

As you can see I have factored the code into a function to make it easier to use. The function will give you an obfuscated email address with:

- A random chop of the original address (taking into account its length)
- A random mask of asterisks

Were I to actually implement this function myself then I would ensure that the email address I am attempting to obfuscate are above 3 characters in length and adjust the `$chop` length appropriately so you can be sure you are hiding as much as possible.